# Issue about too much spacing beneath the footer

Tags: html, css

I tried to look for this issue for more than an hour but unfortunately unable to find where the problem exist. Here is the link for it http://professionals.dev.wbstaging.com/results as you can see at the bottom there is a bigger spacing, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding overflow:hidden to your class .main_container.

```
.main_container {
min-height: 797px;
position: absolute;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You save my day bro it worked! Not sure why the main container gets the space that far, can you provide me an idea?

Comment: Hopefully someone can provide a better answer, but far as I know, overflow:hidden is one of a few ways to clear floated content.